# Hide VSTS/TFS extension's Summary section when extension not added to build task

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have developed VSTS/TFS extension which consists summary page with details generated from our extension task, at the end of build.

we have added contribution similar to below in manifest file  to add this summary section

```
{
            "id": "build-status-section",
            "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section",
            "description": "A section contributing to our own new tab and also to existing build 'summary' tab",
            "targets": [
                ".build-info-tab",
                "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-summary-tab"
            ],
            "properties": {
                 "name": "Custom Section",
                 "uri": "statusSection.html",
                 "order": 20,
                 "height": 500
            }
        }
```

However currently we are facing issue as even when user not add our extension task in to his build our summary page will appear in summary tab (if our extension is installed and enabled).

Is there any way to avoid displaying summary section when our task is not added to their build. Please be kind enough to help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't hide the summary section.

This is because `build-results-summary-tab` is used for all builds. So when you install the extension, even you are not add the task you developed, the summary results will be showed for any of build results.

More details, you can refer [Referencing contributions and types](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/manifest#referencing-contributions-and-types) and the example as [Targetable hub groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview#targetable-hub-groups) shows.

The work around is that you can separate `build-results-summary-tab` extension with the build task extension (use two extensions instead). For the accounts need to view the summary result, they can install the two extensions. Else, the accounts just need to install the extension for the build task.

Comment: Hi @Marina - MSFT, Thanks a lot for your answer. Apart from adding contribution is there any way to add summary section with our build task. I have check and went trough git hub code of sonarcube (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) and I noted even extension is installed when we are not adding extension to task list summary section will not display. However I couldn't find any code related to this in git hub. Please be kind enough to share your thoughts

Comment: This is because the summary section is sonarcube Analysis report which only shows the part about  sonarcube task(s) you added in your build definition. But build-results-summary-tab not only shows summary about a certain task, it's show the whole build results. So they are different.

Comment: Hi @Marina - MSFT, Thanks for the response. can you provide us tips to append summary information dynamically in the build result page. It will be much helpful if you can provide us a sample.

Comment: You can post another question for the details you want to achieve since it's different from this question you asked.

Comment: Hi @Marina - MSFT , I have asked new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222287/display-html-content-in-vsts-tfs-build-summary-without-using-contribution-in-man it would be great help if you can guide me there