# Display HTML content in VSTS/TFS build summary without using contribution in manifest file

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have developed VSTS extension and I need to display graphical content (HTML page) in my VSTS/TFS summary page without using contribution in manifest file. Reason that led me to reject this option (e.g. ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section) is that when we are installed our extension, even if it is not included in current build task list, summary section defined in contribution started to appear in build summary.And this cause bad user experience.

I observed that some extensions such as sonar cube are using different mechanism to display data in summary tab (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube). However I couldn't figure out the way this achieved.

It would be great help if you can provide tips to append summary information dynamically in the build result page. It will be much helpful if you can provide a sample.

This question is related to question I asked in : [Hide VSTS/TFS extension's Summary section when extension not added to build task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169408/hide-vsts-tfs-extensions-summary-section-when-extension-not-added-to-build-task/45181613?noredirect=1#comment77403167_45181613)

Answer (score 3):

Just call `##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path` in your build task.

For example:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=SonarQube Analysis Report;]$reportPath"
```

More information, refer to [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

BTW, about the source code of the extension, you can download the extension and change the file name suffix to XXX.zip, then unzip the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @starain-MSFT I'll try this

Comment: @Lalindu What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?